# OpenCV: Canny edge detector get minEnclosingCircle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using the Canny edge detector to detect an object on a white background and would like to draw a a rectangle and a circle around it. I can get the coordinates for a bounding rectangle but not for the OpenCV functions `minAreaRect` and `minEnclosingCircle`.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(image.path, 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)

#Bounding Rectangle works
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(edges)

#This does not work
(x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(edges)

#This also does not work
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(edges)
```

Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/hschneider/workspace/onspiration/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
>     exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>   File "<ipython-input-28-f9e34ac01335>", line 1, in <module>
>     cv2.minEnclosingCircle(edges)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:160: error: (-215:Assertion failed) count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'minEnclosingCircle'
> ```

I guess, it is because the result of Canny edge detector is in the wrong format but I can't find out how to transform it so that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between these functions is that `boundingRect` works on an image, where as `minEnclosingCircle` and `minAreaRect` work on a 2D point set. To get a point set from the output of `Canny` you could us `findCountours` as suggested in [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html):

```py
# im2, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, 1, 2) # OpenCV 3.x
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)        # OpenCV 4.x
cnt = contours[0]

rect = cv.minAreaRect(cnt)

(x,y),radius = cv.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
```

Comment: I just wanted to add, that the provided `cv.findContours` function call is valid for OpenCV versions 3.x.x. Starting from OpenCV 4.0.0, it was changed to `contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(...)`, see [the doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) for reference.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, I've included that in the answer.